# Two "id" fields in one MongoDB collection with Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I've got a Rails 3.0.9 project using the latest version of MongoDB and Mongoid 2.2.

I imported a CSV with an "id" field into a MongoDB collection named College, resulting in a collection like so:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectID("abc123"), "id" : ######, ... }
```

Observations:

1. The show action results in a URL utilizing the ObjectID
2. Displaying 'college.id' in index.html.erb displays the ObjectID

Questions:

1. How do I use the original "id" field as the parameter
2. Is "id" reserved by MongoDB, meaning I need to rename the "id" field in the
   College collection (perhaps to "code") - if so, how?

Thanks!

**Update**

Answer:

```
db.colleges.update( { "name" : { $exists : true } } , { $rename : { "id" : "code" } }, false, true )
```

I used "name" since that was a field I could check for the existence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

_id is a reserved and required property in MongoDB - I think mongoid is mapping id to _id since that makes sense. There might be a way to access the id property through mongoid but I think you are much better off renaming the id column to something else to avoid confusion in the future.

```
{ $rename : { old_field_name : new_field_name } }
```

will rename the field name in a document (mongo 1.7.2+).

so

```
db.college.update({ "_id" : { $exists : true }}, { $rename : { 'id' : 'code' } }, false, true);
```

should update every record in that collection and rename the id field to code.

(obviously test this before running in any important data)

Comment: The update command needed an additional close bracket } , but even with it, the mongo console returns a Syntax error: `Invalid property id (shell):1`

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the upsert and multi part of `db.collection.update( criteria, objNew, upsert, multi )`? I don't know. I don't know what those parts functionally do.

Comment: The collection name was pluralized `db.colleges.update( { "name" : { $exists : true  } } , { $rename : { "id" : "code"  }  }, false, true  );` and I used "name" since that was another field I could check for the existence, but basically - you were right! Thanks so much!